# Incomplete steering even after new parts install

Tags: dodge, power-steering, ram

I put a new power steering box, power steering pump, and lines on my 98 Dodge Ram 1500 4wd 5.2 truck. It still isn't steering right. When you go to turn the wheel it won't turn all the way one min but then the next min it will. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you bleed the system after putting in new fluid ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Was this the same problem you had before changing out all the parts? Or did this introduce itself after the parts were replaced?